# Changing Flow Control of Com Port via Batch / CMD / Registry / PowerShell / VBScript

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, vbscript, registry

I have tried Modifying the `Registry` Key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports\COM#:` for my specific COM Port in use and it works GREAT! BUT. . . .

It will not set the Flow Control!!  For example - if I change `Flow Control` to `Hardware` the registry entry changes from `9600,n,8,1` to `9600,n,8,1,p` - noting that `,p` is what's changed in the registry. . .  If I change it manually from `Hardware` to `Xon / Xoff`, the registry's `,p` changes to `,x` and if I set it to `None` the final item is removed.

Conversely, if I change this registry manually from `9600,n,8,1` to `9600,n,8,1,p` it will NOT change the `Flow Control`.  It successfully changes everything else, but the Flow Control fails to update. . .

How do I change Flow Control (permanently) via Batch, CMD, PowerShell, VBScript, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it.  The `Registry` to change is not found in the same place (although I would recommend setting the `Registry` entry mentioned in the Question to match what Windows would expect - meaning adding the `,p` to the end of this value.)

The `Registry Key` is `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Serial Print\COM#\` and the `Value` is `FlowControlType`, `Type` is `REG_DWORD` and `Data` is `1` for `Hardware` choice.

Full disclosure:
`FlowControlType` set to `2` = `None`
`FlowControlType` set to `0` = `Xon / Xoff`

Modifying this `Registry` via `CMD`, the `Device Manager` Port settings for selected COM# port shows the change.

If there are any downsides to modifying this vs another method, please provide another answer.  I'll wait a couple days before accepting this answer in case there's a better (Native) way without having to build an executable.